# Nodejs connect to AWS ElasticCache replication group

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services, redis

I have a Redis replication group where I have 1 master and 2 slave nodes. Slave nodes are read only. I am using node_redis to connect to Redis endpoint.

Now I want my application to connect to only slave nodes for any read query and only write query should go to master node. Do I have to make any changes in my application to connect or I can connect to master node and elastic cache will automatically redirect read queries to slave nodes?

Answer (score 0):

Point the 'read queries' to the 'endpoint' of the slave node if used for non-critical purposes.

Another point to note is that data in Slave node 'may' be stale
Keep in mind that primary node can also be used for 'read'

Answer (score -1):

Elasticcache does the load balancing of read queries

Comment: So read only queries I have to update code to use those endpoints or just connecting to primay node will get it done?